# Is it possible to use multiple authentications in a Google Apps Script web-app?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know how to write a web-app and publish it as myself. What I am trying to do is publish a web app so that it can access both my data **and** the users data.

For example, the web-app would read data from a Sheet that **I** own, and then add it to a Sheet the **user** owns.

I realize one approach is to make **my** sheet accessible by anyone with the link and have the web-app run in the **user**'s context. When the **user** views the web-app it will run in the **user**'s context so it can access **their** Sheet and Since **my** sheet is viewable by anyone with a link it will be able to access **my** Sheet.

However, I am trying to do this without making **my** sheet accessible by anyone with a link.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Workaround#1: **Two web apps**

Use two web apps and  handle authentication between those two:

- **WebApp#1: API to access your sheet**

  - Execute as "Me"
  - Access: "Anyone, even anonymous"
  - Handles incoming POST requests:  checks for necessary authorizations, authenticates the request and returns data from sheet.
- **WebApp#2: User facing app**

  - Execute as "User accessing the web app"
  - Access: "Anyone"
  - User requests data from your sheet> Client requests Server(`google.script.run`)> Server POSTs request along with necessary authorization headers using `UrlFetchApp`> receives and parses the sheet data and provides it to client.
- **Notes:**

  - This set up security is only as strong as the authorization/authentication used between the web-apps.

#### Workaround#2:  **Client side Google sign in**

- Implement **Google signin** in your webapp.

  - Execute as "Me"
  - Access: "Anyone, even anonymous"
  - Users accessing the web-app must  sign in
  - After signing in and authorizing access to their sheets, you can use sheets api to  write to their sheet
- **References:**

  - [Google sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/)
  - [Sample snippet: Sheets api access from browser](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js)
  - [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803054/)

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan There is a 3rd (albeit more complex) option where you can leverage a Service Account to access your sheet without sacrificing privacy. The one downside is that this approach requires a GCP project. However, there might be a loophole you can exploit. A service account does not need to be tied to your company's GSuite domain so its possible to create a service account using a separate non-company account and use it in your project. Do you think that your company would be OK with that?

Comment: @DimuDesigns No. I am pretty sure that would get me fired. But I will look into it. I have to find out how to create service accounts first.