# Is there a way to embed (execute) a google app script in a web page other than iframe?

Tags: google-apps-script

since i have some problems in displaying iframe and scrolling it correctly in iPhone browser, i am looking for a way to put the html code of the script directly in my website page.
so can i copy the index.html code from the script and put it in my hosted website?
if no, is there any alternative way?
thanks for any help. [beginner]

Comment: You can just deploy it as a webapp that runs in your browser.

Comment: yes for sure deployed it as web app and got the URL of the script and embedded it in iframe [this works well].

Comment: in another way, can a google app script run from external website html file? the script contain doGet and doPost functions to play with data in google sheet.

Comment: You don't have to embed it as an Iframe in your website.  You can run it as a website in your browser.

Comment: thank for your help, i don't want to redirect the client into anther page and i want to keep the URL of the script hidden.
would the following make sense:
`function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('www.mywebsite.com/index.html');
}`

Comment: I don't think so, but why ask?  Just try and see what happens.  One thing for  sure is that Google won't like getting content from an unsecure site.

Comment: i think i have to authorize the external domain to talk with the app. By the way nice Bike riding! and thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never tried it.  If I want something on a website I iframe it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `POST` from your website and receive it in `doPost()`> execute a Google script function and return information back to your website.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can you please give some few steps to do this?

Comment: @user Don't think I can. If there's a specific thing you want clarified,  I'll be glad to clear it out, but there's nothing more other than those two steps: Post from your website> receive it in doPost(). Also, if you're looking for samples, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+user%3Ame+post+from+web*)

Comment: Thank You the Master. it works! but how to protect my spreadsheet to be only accessible from my domain name.

Comment: and i can post the data but how to get data from the sheet to the web?

Comment: @user314 If you return a value from `doPost()`, it'll be received in web, provided your web app is published as anyone, even anonymous. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57911167/) might help, if you don't want anonymous access to your sheet. If you still have issues, It'll be better to ask a new question with your current code. See [mre].

Comment: Done. Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474081/how-to-return-specific-data-from-a-google-apps-script-into-html-web-page