# how to return specific data from a google apps script into html web page

Tags: html, google-apps-script

**Code.gs**

```
function doPost(e) {
  var id = "SHEET_ID";
  var sheetname = "verify";
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(sheetname).getRange("A1:X100").getValues();
  var ar = [];
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.toString().indexOf(e.searchtext)) {                  
      ar.push(f);
    }    
  });
return ar;
}
```

**www.mywebsite.com/index.html :**

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="gform" method="POST"  action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/SCRIPT_ID/exec" >

<input  name="subject" id="subject" />
<input  name="name" id="name" />

<input type="text" name="searchtext" id="searchtext"  />
<input type="button"  value="Login" id="login" onClick="getData();" />
</form>

<script>
function getData(ar) {
  document.getElementById("name").value=ar[0][1];
  document.getElementById("subject").value=ar[0][2];
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**the Sheet:**

```
A    |    B    |     C
123     John       Green
214     Julie       Red
```

Thanks in Advance for any help,

First: how to return the data to my website page.

Second: i dont want to submit the form. i want to get the data and use them in the same page.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Can you explain about your script and the current issue of your script? 2. About `i want to get the data and use them in the same page.`, how do you want to use the data retrieved from `doPost`? Is your goal of your question is only you retrieve the value from `doPost`?

Comment: The script doesnt work, it redirect to the script url and returns wrong value type error. If i change the function to ```doGet```  and the method into "GET" nothing happens. About the value yes i need to use the name and subject values in the form before submitting.

Comment: I don't understand the use of the bitwise invert here `if (~f.toString().indexOf(e.searchtext)) { `  and shouldn't `e.searchtext` be `e.parameter.searchtext`?

Comment: When added i can search for text / with numbers. About e.searchtext and the whole code is working from the html page of the script. The problem appears when i tried to call the script from external html web page.

Answer (score 0):

For what I could understand you want to pass some values to your server side (your Apps Script code) when you submit a form (Preventing the default submitting form behavior). If that's correct, then use the following code in your HTML file.

### html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="gform">
      <input  id="subject" />
      <input  id="name" />
      <input type="text" id="searchtext"/>
      <button>Submit form</button>
    </form>
  <script>
    // Callback that runs when the valuesSubmitted function returned some values 
    function onSuccess(val){
      console.log(val);
    }
    
    // Callback that runs when the form is submitted
    function logSubmit(e){
      // Get values from the inputs 
      var submittedVals = {
        "subject": document.getElementById('subject').value,
        "name": document.getElementById('name').value,
        "searchtext": document.getElementById('searchtext').value
      }
      
      // Pass data to the server side 
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).valuesSubmitted(submittedVals);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    
    // Event listener for when the form is submitted
    document.getElementById('gform').addEventListener('submit', logSubmit);
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The key concept in the JavaScript code is the [***Class google.script.run***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run), which is a powerful tool that allows you to call your Apps Script functions in the server-side. Using [`withSuccessHandler(function)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction) you will be able to wait for an Apps Script function to return a value to run later a callback function with the gotten values.

***Notice:*** I also used `.preventDefault()` to cancel the form's submit behavior.

Now, in your Apps Script code, you will have defined the function that can get the spreadsheet's values in order to pass them to your client-side:

### Apps Script

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

// Called using google.script.run
function valuesSubmitted(val){
  // Values that came from the client side  
  Logger.log(val);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = sheet.getRange("Any range you want").getValues();
  // Pass data to the client side
  return data;
}
```

I didn't do it exactly as in your code, Take my post as guidance and modify it in the parts of the code we have different if you want to.

Comment: Thank you alberto for your answer but with your codes the script says: No HTML file named index was found. (line 2, file "Code", project "projectname")

Comment: Are you using [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) from Apps Script? If you do, then change the argument in this line of code ```.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')```  to the name of your html file

Comment: My html file is index.html but it is hosted on firebase hosting server.

Comment: Now I get it, The way you are intending to use ```doGet()/doPost()``` is not possible, If it fits you well, instead of hosting your HTML in Firebase, I would suggest you, to have your project as an [Apps Script Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)(if you choose this way my answer can help you), if you don't want it in that way, then to be able to connect to your Apps Script code, I recommend you to check [App Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts).

Comment: You're welcome, if my answer helped you, consider mark it as the correct answer