# Auth to Execute GSheet Script by Non-Owner

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 3 types of users:

- Manager (1)
- Captain (1)
- Players (n)

I have 2 types of sheets:

- Master (1)
- Details (n)

The manager is the owner of all sheets.
The players can only see and read their respective Details.

My question relates to the Captain who is supposed to:

- edit the Master and
- execute a script within the Master which moves the data from the Master to the Details

In the script I am planning to put a check like:

```
if (thisUser == 'Manager@gmail.com' ...
```

BUT how do I authorise the Captain to execute the script and post data in a sheet in the Details-sheets for which the Captain is not editor nor reader?

Comment: Why not make captain editor of all details sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Publish a webapp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) from a [standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) by Manager:
- Execute as: me
- Access: anyone
- Include a `doPost` function, which will execute moving data from "Master" to "Details"
- Share the script with "Captain"
- In "Manager" sheet, Add a script function(say, `postToWebApp`) to `post`( using `UrlFetchApp` + `ScriptApp.getAccessToken()`) to the standalone webapp.
- Now, "Captain" can execute `postToWebApp` and post  relevant data to the webapp to start moving data from "Master" to "Details" under authority of "Manager".
- You need to use additional authentication/ authorization security measures like HMAC to make sure no one else can do  the same(as the webapp is published  with Access: Anyone).
- Related Answer: [Is there a way to let a user edit another spreadsheet with a script and hide it from him at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63686862)